# How to send data from a picker IN a collectionview to an API endpoint using MVVM (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, picker, collectionview

For my current project I am working on a cross-platform application. We are building this using Visual studio, cross platform-app.
In this project we use questionaires which we set in an SQL Database.

Using MVVM I **can** load this dynamically into the mobile app. (We do this because there are many platforms where we show this, so we choose to set it in the back-end, the questionaire with the answers to each question).

But with saving there seems to be an issue,
I can't seem to send data back to my back end
-> I want to send either the value or the string showed from the picker back to the back end (preferably using MVVM). If I can get the data in the viewmodel (or code behind if MVVM would not be possible), i would be helped enough with my question.

I build my questionaire using a collectionview which contains a DataTemplate with a picker inside.

**QuestionaireView.xaml:**

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:Questionaire_viewmodel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
<CollectionView
                x:Name="CollectionQuestionsView"
                SelectionMode="None"
                Margin="0,0,0,0" RemainingItemsThreshold="5" 
                BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                SelectedItems="{Binding selectedPickers}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Questionaire.Vraag,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource RegularLabelStyleSmallLogin}" Text="{Binding vraagstelling}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                            <Picker Style="{StaticResource PickRegularSmall}" SelectedItem="{Binding vraag_id}" x:Name="{Binding vraag_id}" ItemsSource="{Binding Antwoorden}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding antwoord_vraagstelling}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
            <Frame Margin="0,0,0,20" Style="{StaticResource OrangeLoginFrame}">
                <Grid Margin="-15" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource SemiBoldLabelStyleMedium}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Opslaan"/>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource LoginButton}" Command="{Binding SaveVragenlijstCompetentiesCommand}" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" />
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
            <Button x:Name="questionaireButton" Command="{Binding getQuestionaireLoopbaancompetenties}" IsVisible="False"/>
```

So to explain the bindings (since some names are not English):

- itemsource of collectionview: The questionaire.vraag retrieves a collection of questions out of the questionaire object (see the model.cs down below)
- label text binding: Displays the question
- picker selectedItem binding: vraag id results in a string (retrieved from the backend) which here specifly is vraag_127, vraag_128 (the numbers are an id of the question)
- itemsource picker: binding antwoorden, these are the answers to the questions
- in the frame below the collectionview, I made a button to (at least i tried) to send the data to the ViewModel.cs
- The (hidden)button below the frame loads the data (I execute it in the code behind, not sure if this is the best option)

**QuestionaireViewModel.cs**

```
        public string vraag_127 { get; set; }
        public string vraag_128 { get; set; }
        ... and so on
        public string vraag_161 { get; set; }

        public string categorie_vraag { get; set; }
        public string SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
        public string vraagstelling { get; set; }
        public string vraag_id { get; set; }
        public string score_antwoord { get; set; }
        public string antwoord_vraagstelling { get; set; }
        public string default_question { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
private Questionaire_model _questionaire;
        public Questionaire_model Questionaire
        {
            get { return _questionaire; }
            set
            {
                _questionaire = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }

        private List<Questionaire_model> _vraag;
        public List<Questionaire_model> Vraag
        {
            get { return _vraag; }
            set
            {
                _vraag = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }



        private List<Questionaire_model> _antwoorden;
        public List<Questionaire_model> Antwoorden
        {
            get { return _antwoorden; }
            set
            {
                _antwoorden = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }

        public ICommand getQuestionaireLoopbaancompetenties
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async (boolean) =>
                {
                    Questionaire = await _apiServices.GetQuestionaireQuestions("Competenties");
                });
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<vragenModel> _selectedPicker;

        public ObservableCollection<vragenModel> SelectedPicker
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedPicker;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedPicker = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public ICommand SaveVragenlijstCompetentiesCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {

                    var responseBool = await _apiServices.SaveCultuur(vraag_127,vraag_128, ... vraag_161)});
            }
        }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyname = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
```

**And my QuestionaireModel.cs**:

```
public class Questionaire_model
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string default_question { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public IList<Vragen> Vraag{ get; set; }

        public class Vragen
        {
            public string categorie_vraag { get; set; }
            public string SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
            public string vraagstelling { get; set; }
            public string vraag_id { get; set; }
            public IList<antwoorden> Antwoorden { get; set; }
        }
        public class antwoorden
        {
            public string score_antwoord { get; set; }
            public string antwoord_vraagstelling { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The reason we use an collectionView, is because we use the template for various questionaires with various amount of questions and answer possibilities.

So at this moment, when I execute my save action, it gives "null" in my ViewModel - action
I have defined *`public class Questionaire_viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged`* above my viewmodel

So I hope someone can either help me with my code, that I missed something here
Or if I have to change something because it is simply impossible well then I would like to have an direction where to go to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want your `Picker.SelectedItem` actually bind to `QuestionaireViewModel.vrag_xxx` properties. That won't work like this - what now happens is that your `Picker.SelectedItem` is bound to `Vragen.vraag_id` field and is not able to use it, as long as it expects `antwoorden` type there.

However, I see that you have `SelectedAnswer` property in `Vragen`, you can change it to be of `antwoorden` type and then fetch user choice from that field.
So, if your `Vragen` class is:

```cs
public class Vragen
{
    public string categorie_vraag { get; set; }
    public antwoorden SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
    public string vraagstelling { get; set; }
    public string vraag_id { get; set; }
    public IList<antwoorden> Antwoorden { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can change your binding for `Picker` to:

```xml
<Picker Style="{StaticResource PickRegularSmall}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAnswer}" x:Name="{Binding vraag_id}" ItemsSource="{Binding Antwoorden}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding antwoord_vraagstelling}"/>
```

And, at last in `SaveVragenlijstCompetentiesCommand` you'll be able to get array of answers (sorted by question id):

```cs
Questionaire.Vraag.OrderBy(x => x.vraag_id).Select(x => x.SelectedAnswer.antwoord_vraagstelling)
```

That will give you array of answer texts. Still it doesn't conform to your `apiServices.SaveCultuur` call. I would strongly recommend to change that method - method that contains a lot of parameters is certainly a problem.
If you can change it to accept `string[]`, then you will be able to pass `Questionaire.Vraag.OrderBy(x => x.vraag_id).Select(x => x.SelectedAnswer.antwoord_vraagstelling)` to it.
If you can't change `apiServices`, there's still possibility to call the method through reflection using array, but it's a bit tricky.

Comment: Thank you. I appearently needed to change this in my viewmodel.cs as in my model.cs; Further this worked perfectly for me. 
Also thanks for the additional tips, I will look further into it, to improve it.